# Business need to send secure information over email automatically, via PHP

Tags: php, security, zip

I have a business need to send some secure text to an email address within our internal PHP application.  The sensative info is entered by user(s), processed, then emailed out.  It is deleted from the server as soon as the email is sent - thus avoiding any storage of the information on the server.

I've been investigating the *easiest* methods to send this over email to users who are not tech savvy.  I.E., installing PGP on their PCs is ideally not the solution (or some other complex encryption method).

What are the thoughts on zip passwords - and emailing this zip file out that contains a txt file with the sensitive information (I'm thinking about the built-into-CentOS zip + password from command line method)?  Is this insecure in any way that I'm overlooking?  I'm talking about command line zip - i.e. `$zipCmd = "/usr/bin/zip -P $ZIP_PASS xxxx";`

What other options might be good that I'm not thinking about?

Thanks all.

Comment: Is sending an email that directs them to a secure webpage an option?  Just because you've deleted the message off *your* server, it is still in the clear for the entirety of its transit, as well as could be stored at any point along its delivery path (your server is not the only place where it might be kept).

Comment: Are you talking about creating a file of passwords, zipping them, then emailing the contents of the zip file? Not sure what you mean by 'zip passwords'.

Comment: @joe if I HAVE to, I can temporarily store the data... but this is a far less than ideal solution for me.

Comment: GPG goes for Gnu version of PGP, so it stands, sir.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision, I edited the post a bit.  I'm talking about the command line zip utility, and using `-P` to apply a password to the zip file.  @MitchWheat - ha, sorry got a little dyslexic.

Comment: @Shackrock: gotcha. So you want to password protect the zip file, then provide the password to the recipient as a form of data protection.

Comment: @Shackrock: How are you retrieving this data? according to your OP and response to Brad, sounds like the data resides on the database until you fetch it, then email, then remove data from your database?

Comment: @DigitalPrecision yes exactly.  I don't even need a zip... but a zip is certainly an easy way for the end-user to download the file from the email, and extract after entering the correct password to the zip file (even in windows w/ no other software).

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you know, e-mail is not secure.  The only thing you can do is encrypt the payload, or don't send the message directly.

There are many tools available for cracking ZIP passwords.

I would recommend what is typically done elsewhere... Store the message on a server, require SSL and some sort of credentials for accessing it.  This doesn't sound like a drop-in process for what you are doing, but I suspect it is your best option.

Comment: I can certainly do that... however my issue is the long term storage of the secure information on the server.  I suppose I could delete the information after X days, but I really don't ever want it there for more than a few hours if I have my way.

Comment: I would trust your server far more than I'd trust someone's e-mail.

Comment: but then the liability is on me and my server =(.

Comment: @Shackrock: if yuu're sending sensitive data in the clear, it's on you anyway.

Comment: @Shackrock, If you are not confident in your server security, hire a company who specializes in this sort of thing to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your OP, and responses to other posts and comments.

You are already storing the data on your database, so whatever liability you think you are escaping by getting it off the server ASAP, is a false positive. What if a hacker were to access your system before you generate one of these reports? Your in just as much hot water as you would be if you were storing the data for the long term, granted it would be less impact because there would be less rows, but you would still be exposed.

IMO, it's far more dangerous to email 'sensitive' data than it would be for you to offer up a SSL connection with user authentication. No data is 100% safe, but if you follow industry guidelines for protecting your data (encryption, authenticate user credentials etc.), then you will be far more protected.

If you truly fear housing the data on your system, maybe take a look at a CDN which specializes in the storing of sensitive data. You could have your app hook into their API and store the data.

The other issue is that if you are chunking out data to send in an email, how are you making certain you don't miss any data? Is your database supporting thousands of QPS (queries per second)?

Comment: As of now, there is no sensative data in the DB.  My original idea was to process the form immediately in a single script, and email out the final data.  The only storage would be the temporary variable for the POST request...  Do you know any CDN's that do this sort of thing?